# Update multiple rows in Excel table with MS Graph API

Tags: excel, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

In the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablerow-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)  there is a way to update a single row of an excel table like:

```
 PATCH /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/workbook/tables/{id|name}/rows/$/ItemAt(index=1)
```

Is there any way to update multiple(all) rows in the table with single request? There are 10 Tables with 200+ rows, so that's not an option to make 10*200=2000 single PATCH requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the [following API:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
PATCH /me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/tables/{id|name}/columns/{id|name}/range
```

Example:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/driveId/items/fileId/workbook/tables/tableName/columns/ColumnName/range

{
    "values": [
        [
            "ColumnName"
        ],
        [
            "Row1"
        ],
        [
            "Row2"
        ]
    ]
}
```